# Recursive Find And Update items in State of a TreeView Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a Treeview component with react and it accepts items like this

```
 [{
    id: string;
    parent: string | null;
    name: string;
    children: TreeData[];
    isOpen?: boolean;
    isFolder?: boolean;
    code?: string;
}]
```

I made a function to recursively add a new folder or file in every selected tree node in treeview

```
const updateItem = (data: TreeData[], newFile: TreeData): TreeData[] => {
    return data.map((item: TreeData) => {
      if (item.id === dfs(item, selectedItem.id).id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          children: [...item.children, newFile],
          
        };
      }
      else if (
        item.id !== dfs(item, selectedItem.id).id &&
        item.children &&
        item.children.length > 0
      ) {
        updateItem(item.children, newFile);
      }

      return item;
    });
  };
```

and dfs function:

```
 const dfs = (obj: TreeData, targetId: any) => {
    if (obj.id === targetId) {
      return obj;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
      for (let item of obj.children) {
        let check: any = dfs(item, targetId);
        if (check) {
          return check;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
```

but it won't work correctly and it won't update the Treeview more than 2 level

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```ts
interface TreeData {
  id: string;
  parent?: string | null;
  name?: string;
  children: TreeData[];
  isOpen?: boolean;
  isFolder?: boolean;
  code?: string;
}

const updateItem = (
  data: TreeData[],
  selectedItemId: string,
  newFile: TreeData
) => {
  data.forEach((item: TreeData) => {
    const found = dfs(item, selectedItemId);
    if (found) {
      found.children.push(newFile);
    } else if (!found && item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
      updateItem(item.children, selectedItemId, newFile);
    }
  });
};

const dfs = (obj: TreeData, targetId: string): TreeData | null => {
  if (obj.id === targetId) {
    return obj;
  }
  if (obj.children) {
    for (let item of obj.children) {
      let check: TreeData | null = dfs(item, targetId);
      if (check) {
        return check;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const allData: TreeData[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    children: [{ id: "6", children: [] }],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    children: [
      { id: "7", children: [] },
      { id: "8", children: [{ id: "9", children: [] }] },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    children: [
      {
        id: "10",
        children: [
          {
            id: "11",
            children: [{ id: "12", children: [{ id: "13", children: [] }] }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    children: [{ id: "5", children: [] }],
  },
];

const selectedItem: TreeData = {
  id: "13",
  children: [],
};
const newFile = { id: "14", children: [] };
updateItem(allData, selectedItem.id, newFile);

console.log(
  allData[2].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]
); // {id: 14, children:[]}
```